# Compare two arrays contains integers, return the difference

Tags: php, arrays, integer, difference

I want to compare 2 `arrays` with `integers`.

what I have:

```
function findDeletedNumber(array $arr, array $mixedArr): int {
  $diff = array_diff($arr, $mixedArr);
  if ($diff != NULL) { return($diff); }
  return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that I need to return the difference as a `string`. Not an `array`. the difference is always gonna be only one value

Comment: return(implode(',',$diff)) ?

Comment: @mickmackusa I found my solution. The returned value is always gonna be one value. So I did this function `findDeletedNumber(array $arr, array $mixedArr): int { return array_sum($arr) - array_sum($mixedArr); }`

Answer (score 0):

use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

```
function findDeletedNumber(array $arr, array $mixedArr): int {
      $diff = array_diff($arr, $mixedArr);
      if ($diff != NULL) { return(implode(',',$diff)); }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your function name, you are returning one number at most, you can use current() like this:

```
return ($diff=array_diff($arr,$mixedArr))?current($diff):0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned value is always gonna be one value. You can use `array_sum` to sum the integers. Just substract the awnsers of summed array, and that's the difference.

```
findDeletedNumber(array $arr, array $mixedArr): int 
{ 
  return array_sum($arr) - array_sum($mixedArr); 
}
```